# SoP to PoS conversion in the simplest way

Tags: digital-logic

I have an exam in digital electronics in the middle of april and I've been trying for weeks to understand how F = B'C' + AC + A'C' in SoP can become (A+C')(A'+B'+C) in PoS. Could someone please take me through, step by step, either throught karnaugh map or normal SoP to PoS, how to do this particular problem?

Comment: K-map is the simplest. Draw one for SOP, then go with covering zeros to get POS....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with a karnaugh map:

[image]

Then go through your SoPs.  The first is B'C', so you update it as follows:

[image]

Then AC:

[image]

And finally A'C':

[image]

Fill in the rest with 0s:

[image]

Next determine the equations for the zeros.  For this 0:

[image]

use the (ABC')' = A' + B' + C

For this pair of 0s:

[image]

use (A'C)' = A + C'

In order for neither of the zero cases (the singleton or pair) to take affect, multiply the two expressions and get (A+C')(A'+B'+C)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful

Comment: you're very welcome!